# Finding mean and standard deviation of a large dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have about 1500 files on S3 (each file looks like this:)

Format :
UserId \t ItemId:Score,ItemdId:Score,ItemId:Score \n
UserId \t ItemId:Score,ItemdId:Score,ItemId:Score \n

I read the file as:

```
import scala.io.Source
val FileRead = Source.fromFile("/home/home/testdataFile1").mkString
```

Here is an example of what I get:

1152    401368:1.006,401207:1.03
1184    401230:1.119,40049:1.11,40029:1.31

How do I compute the average and standard deviation of the variable 'Score'?

Comment: given you added 'spark' tag (I edited to apache-spark) Are you looking on how to do this on apache-spark?

Answer (score 13):

While it's not explicit in the question, [**Apache Spark**](http://spark.apache.org/) is a good tool for doing this in a distributed way. I assume you have set up a Spark cluster. Read the files into an RDD:

```
val lines: RDD[String] = sc.textFile("s3n://bucket/dir/*")
```

Pick out the "score" somehow:

```
val scores: RDD[Double] = lines.map(_.split(":").last.toDouble).cache
```

`.cache` saves it in memory. This avoids re-reading the files all the time, but can use a lot of RAM. Remove it if you want to trade speed for RAM.

Calculate the metrics:

```
val count = scores.count
val mean = scores.sum / count
val devs = scores.map(score => (score - mean) * (score - mean))
val stddev = Math.sqrt(devs.sum / (count - 1))
```

Comment: just a tip to shorten the code: you can replace *scores.reduce(_ + _)* with *scores.sum*

Comment: Population stddev, you omit the Bessel correction for sample stdev.

Comment: Yes - you often see stdev examples which don't distinguish between sample and population stdev, and omit explaining the difference.

Answer (score 2):

This question is not new, so maybe I can update the answers.

There are stddev functions (`stddev`, `stddev_pop`, and `stddev_smap`) is SparkSQL (`import org.apache.spark.sql.functions`) since spark version >= 1.6.0.

Answer (score 1):

I use Apache Commons Math for this stuff (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/stat.html), albeit from Java.  You can stream stuff through the SummaryStatistics class so you aren't limited to the size of memory.  Scala to Java interop should allow you to do this, but I haven't tried it.  You should be able to each your way through the File line by line and stream the stuff through an instance of SummaryStatistics.  How hard could it be in Scala?

Lookie here, someone is off and Scala-izing the whole thing:  https://code.google.com/p/scalalab/wiki/ApacheCommonMathsLibraryInScalaLab

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that storage space should be an issue so I would try putting all of the values into an array of doubles then adding up all of the values then use that and the number of elements in the array to calculate the mean.Then add up all of the absolute values of the differences between the value in the mean and divide that by the number of elements. Then take the square root.

Comment: I'd ask the size of each file before thinking they fit in memory.

Comment: @maasg More precisely: how many users per file and how many scores per user?  And are the scores for one user all in the same file, or can be spread across multiple files?

Comment: @maasg, toto2 : I kind of architected Each file to about 40 Mb, an average of 100k users per file, total of 1500 files on s3.